# Automator to save all images in multiple mail messages

Tags: macbook-pro, email, automator, graphics

Is it possible to use automator to save all images from my Mail? I use Apple mail with 3 accounts, I want to filter messages by a criteria and get all the images from the messages? Can anyone tell me how can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

I just tried this and it seemed to work, though you'll have to play with it.
[image]